# Finding minimum set length

Tags: r, set, data.table

I have meter readings per month and year:

```
df = read.table(header = T, text = "
year    month   meter
2012    1   A
2012    2   A
2013    1   A
2013    2   A
2012    1   B
2012    2   B
2013    1   B
2013    2   B
2012    1   D
2012    2   D ")
```

**Question**: how can I get the set of meters that have been active throughout the metered periods [the minimum set length, see below] ?

E.g. for this sample dataset the outcome would be:

```
2012 / 1 = {A,B,D}
2012 / 2 = {A,B,D}
2013 / 1 = {A,B}
2013 / 2 = {A,B}
# minimum set length = {A,B}

# I have made the datasets in data.table but get stuck at the final bit;
# probably a set operation over column V1 below.
require(data.table)    
df = data.table(df)
(df.sets = df[,paste0(unique(meter),collapse = ','), keyby = list(year,month)])
```

Comment: how do you use the minimum set length? It is not clear

Comment: Do you just mean the one with the fewest members? If so, what if there were two with 2 members each, one with `A,B` and one with `A,D`?

Comment: @RockScience : the minimum set length is the set of meters that have been used throughout the monitoring period. In the example above it is {A,B} for both 2013/1 and 2013/2.

Comment: @jbaums If the result in rows is {A,B} and {A,D} then the final result is {A} - only A has been active throughout all periods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the function ?split

```
names(which(sapply(split.data.frame(df,f=df$meter),nrow)==nrow(unique(df[,c("year","month")]))))
```

Comment: Thanks RockScience - this gives a solution for the sets [levels], but does not yet answer the question which is the minimum set.

Comment: I have changed my answer given the new details you gave

Comment: Thanks  - works on the sample data, but somehow not on the actual dataset ["NULL"]. Names and structure of sample data and dataset are identical. I have no missing data.

Comment: That means that there was no meter active for ALL the dates. In this case you need to take the minimum approach suggested by @jbaums. Note that this seems to be a different issue than the one explained in your  question. SO is not to solve an entire project, but an isolated issue.

Comment: if there has been no meter active for ALL the dates, then that is exactly the answer to the question. In the sample data it was {A,B}, in the real data NULL. The different outcome does not make it an isolated issue.